# Magento/Solr - where to run the Solr daemon on a 2 server system?

Tags: solr, magento

I got almost no experience with Solr, so please bear with me, if the answer is obvious:

In a Magento Enterprise 1.11 shop system (about 30k products), where one machine mainly serves the web requests and another machine is dedicated for database requests, does it generally make more sense to run a Solr daemon on the webserver machine, or on the database machine?

Can please someone explain me, *whether* it makes a difference and *why*?

#### Edit

Webserver machine:

> Red Hat ES 5, IX E5405 Quad Core, 16 GB RAM, 2x160 GB SATA RAID1
>
> top - 18:24:32 up 139 days,  8:04,  1 user,  load average: 2.12, 1.94,
> 2.14 Tasks: 168 total,   1 running, 167 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0
> zombie Cpu(s): 38.4%us,  1.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 59.9%id,  0.0%wa,  0.1%hi,
> 0.2%si,  0.0%st Mem:  16431252k total, 15924128k used,   507124k free,
> 890988k buffers Swap:  2040244k total,      140k used,  2040104k free,
> 11607440k cached

Database machine:

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5, IX X3430 Quad Core, 8 GB RAM, 2x450 GB SAS RAID1
>
> top - 18:28:02 up 139 days,  8:04,  1 user,  load average: 0.16, 0.23,
> 0.24 Tasks: 109 total,   1 running, 108 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0
> zombie Cpu(s):  1.9%us,  0.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 95.6%id,  0.5%wa,  0.0%hi,
> 1.5%si,  0.0%st Mem:   8164004k total,  7863308k used,   300696k free,
> 228608k buffers Swap:  2097144k total,      120k used,  2097024k free,
> 3584672k cached

Comment: What is the typical current load, memory usage and disk utilisation on the two servers? Are the server specs the same?

Comment: @NickDownton: updated my question. I'm not sure though, how to get more informative memory usage and disk utilisation values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When load testing split Magento web/db servers with similar specs, I've noticed that the webserver CPU tends to max out while the database server CPU utilization stays fairly low (this was expected behavior). That leads me to believe Solr will run more effectively on the database server as long as both servers have adequate memory available.

Try it yourself by watching the `top` command on both servers while load testing.

Comment: Tested both setups. In our case Solr on the dedicated database server yielded better results. Thank you.